# SQL Server trigger after insert to another database is not firing

Tags: sql-server, triggers

Previously I had a `TRIGGER` in `Table46` to fire after an insert to send a message to another server using Service Broker, which was working fine:

```
  CREATE TRIGGER trgSendItemData
    ON [dbo].[Table46]
    AFTER INSERT
    AS
        DECLARE @new_event XML;
        SET @new_event = (
            SELECT    i.[046_ID] AS [id]
                    , NP.NoPart + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), T41.[041_No]) AS [name]
                    , DATEADD(MINUTE, -1 * i.[046_ExeTime], i.[046_DateTime]) AS [eventstart]
                    , i.[046_DateTime] AS [eventend]
                    , i.[046_IDRes] AS [resource_id]
                    , i.[046_ExeTime] AS [execution]
                    , ISNULL(MIN(T48.[048_MachTime]), 0) AS [same]
                    , ISNULL(MIN(T48_1.[048_MachTime]), 0) AS [all]
                    , i.[046_Pallet] AS [pallet]
            FROM inserted AS i
                INNER JOIN Table41 AS T41
                    ON i.[046_IDOp] = T41.[041_IDOp]
                INNER JOIN NoParts AS NP
                    ON T41.[041_IDNoPart] = NP.Autonumber
                INNER JOIN Table48 AS T48
                    ON i.[046_IDRes] = T48.[048_IDRes]
                    AND i.[046_IDOp] = T48.[048_IDOp]
                INNER JOIN Table48 AS T48_1
                    ON i.[046_IDOp] = T48_1.[048_IDOp]
            GROUP BY i.[046_ID], NP.NoPart, T41.[041_No], i.[046_MachTime], 
                    i.[046_DateTime], i.[046_IDRes], i.[046_ExeTime], i.[046_Pallet];
            FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS
        );

        DECLARE @ConvHandle UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;
        BEGIN TRANSACTION
            BEGIN DIALOG @ConvHandle
                FROM SERVICE SenderService
                TO SERVICE 'ReceiverService'
                ON CONTRACT STContract
                WITH ENCRYPTION = OFF;

                SEND ON CONVERSATION @ConvHandle
                    MESSAGE TYPE SenderMsg (@new_event);
        COMMIT TRANSACTION;
GO
```

Now I need that same data in a table of another database but in the same server, so I wrote this one which is not working:

```
USE Database1
GO

CREATE TRIGGER trgSendEvent
    ON [dbo].[Table46]
    AFTER INSERT
    AS BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        INSERT INTO [Database2].[dbo].[Events]
           ([id]
           ,[name]
           ,[eventstart]
           ,[eventend]
           ,[resource_id]
           ,[execution]
           ,[same]
           ,[all]
           ,[pallet])
        SELECT    i.[046_ID] AS [id]
                , NP.NoPart + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), T41.[041_No]) AS [name]
                , DATEADD(MINUTE, -1 * i.[046_ExeTime], i.[046_DateTime]) AS [eventstart]
                , i.[046_DateTime] AS [eventend]
                , i.[046_IDRes] AS [resource_id]
                , i.[046_ExeTime] AS [execution]
                , ISNULL(MIN(T48.[048_MachTime]), 0) AS [same]
                , ISNULL(MIN(T48_1.[048_MachTime]), 0) AS [all]
                , i.[046_Pallet] AS [pallet]
        FROM inserted AS i
            INNER JOIN Table41 AS T41
                ON i.[046_IDOp] = T41.[041_IDOp]
            INNER JOIN NoParts AS NP
                ON T41.[041_IDNoPart] = NP.Autonumber
            INNER JOIN Table48 AS T48
                ON i.[046_IDRes] = T48.[048_IDRes]
                AND i.[046_IDOp] = T48.[048_IDOp]
            INNER JOIN Table48 AS T48_1
                ON i.[046_IDOp] = T48_1.[048_IDOp]
        GROUP BY i.[046_ID], NP.NoPart, T41.[041_No], i.[046_MachTime], 
                i.[046_DateTime], i.[046_IDRes], i.[046_ExeTime], i.[046_Pallet];
    END;
GO
```

I know that it isn't working because if I manually run a query to insert a new row in `Table46`, the new row is added in `Table46`, but not in `Database2.Events`. This is what I get as output:

```
(1 row affected)
```

Should I get that twice instead?

Also, `Table46` constantly receives data but when the trigger is created it stops receiving it.

I also tried running a query to enable the trigger in case it's disabled, but nothing changes.

Comment: If you do not get any input into `Database2.Events` and also do not get an error, this is most likely because your `SELECT` statement does not return any values. Try refining the select statements and the INNER JOINs especially. For debug purposes, you can use the PRINT command to print a message in your output from within the trigger. This verifies that your trigger is being executed.

Comment: For debugging purposes, try changing the INNER joins to LEFT joins and see what you get then.  If that doesn't work then you may need to add some TRY/CATCHs and some explicit PRINT statements to trace it.  I suspect that you are getting errors (not just no data from the INNER joins), but some setting/difference is causing them to not be reported to your manual queries.  If all else fails, you may have to use the Profiler to see what is really going on.

Comment: unluckily none of that worked. Yesterday I lost almost all day trying to fix this but I couldn't, so today I just configured a local Service Broker and it's working fine.